# Astro js dynamic nested routing.. Is this right approach?

Tags: javascript, astrojs

say, there is an app shows football match data of several leagues. The match data comes from external apis.

Here is the routing. I want to show a top page for each league and monthly pages which shows match data by the month.

### page structure

```
[league]
|- [month].astro
| index.astro
```

### Routing for [league] index.astro

I make api requests within `getStaticPaths()` and create routing data like this.

```
export function getStaticPaths() {
  // api requests, then create routing data.
  return [
    { params: { league: "Bundesliga" }},
    { params: { league: "Laliga" }},
    { params: { league: "EnglishPremierLeague" }},
  ];
}
```

### Routing for [month].astro

So, I should probably need data like this.

```
return [
  { params: { league: "Bundesliga", month: "2023-04" } },
  { params: { league: "Bundesliga", month: "2023-05" } },
  { params: { league: "Bundesliga", month: "2023-06" } },
  { params: { league: "Bundesliga", month: "2023-06" } },
  { params: { league: "Laliga", month: "2023-06" } },
  { params: { league: "Laliga", month: "2023-07" } },
  { params: { league: "Laliga", month: "2023-08" } },
  { params: { league: "Laliga", month: "2023-09" } },
  { params: { league: "EnglishPremierLeague", month: "2023-12" } },
  { params: { league: "EnglishPremierLeague", month: "2024-01" } },
];
```

But this method seems too verbose, because to create data like this, you need another api requests from every routing files.

Is there any better way to do it? like making just one request and create all possible routing data patterns and can be referenced from routing astro files?

Comment: I should just use store? see if it works...

Comment: OK. store was not for saving routing data. I guess I just make api calls from [month].astro. that seems to be a right way to do it since it will be done while building.